# How to embed a web browser inside a web app made in node.js ?

Tags: node.js, browser

I currently have a web app made in `node.js`. One feature of this app is to take notes. I want to provide the user with a way to browse the internet and select a text to add as a note in our web app without having to manually copy-pasting from one browser window to our app.

I know I can do this relatively simply using a Chrome extension that would be linked to the user account and would save the note to the database. However, I cannot use this approach since not all my users can install Google Chrome.

Therefore, I am looking for a way to browse the web from inside our web app. For example, it could be in an iFrame where we display a `complete` browser. That way, the user could navigate the web for information from inside the app, select text to save and click on a button (probably located outside the iFrame browser) to save the selected text as a note in our database.

How can I achieve such a thing in `node.js` ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean that you have a traditional server-client web app where the client is whatever browser the user wants to run and the server is written in Node.js?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. And I want to avoid the manual solution where the user opens a second browser instance (a new tab or a new window) to copy-paste text to our app. Ideally, the user would never have to leave our app.

Answer (score 0):

This is, essentially, impossible.

For you to get any data about the site the user was browsing you could either:

- Restrict them to browsing sites willing to partner with you to give you permission to access their data via `postMessage` (a technical change on their part to work around the Same Origin Policy)
- Proxy every request through your server which would:

  - Have large bandwidth requirements
  - Require a lot of rewriting of URLs (including dynamically generated ones in JS)
  - Require rewriting of X-Frames-Options and Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers
  - Need users who would trust you with all the data you passed through your system (including their passwords to third party sites)
  - Not work for Intranet sites (since your server could not reach them)

Comment: Isant true, foundry vtt do exactly this. Foundry open the browser with specific configuratuon